# Does Silverlight have the notion of SecurityPrincipal or something similar?

Tags: silverlight

We depend on a custom SecurityPrincipal for Authorization in our WCF Services and WPF Applications.

Does Silverlight (4 & Above) have something similar? If yes, how do I set it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Identity Developer Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14347) has a sample with a mocked IClaimsPrincipal being used in the Silverlight client. The sample deals with claims based authentication, but the technique is similar.